# can one have multiple html files in a single template directory in django?

Tags: django, templates, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a templates directory with two other directories, home, and diagnosis each directory having its own respective HTML file. So I want to know if that's the best way to do it or am I doing it the wrong way?

[Link to access the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdcEP.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Your question's answer is easily get from this site [SimpleIsBetterThanComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html#views-templates-and-static-files)
This site is provide easy way to learn for beginner's ....

Comment: yes this is really good for beginner, and i was glad to appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

I've read **Two Scoops of Django Best Practices For Django** book and it really provides the best practices to use Django, in the templates chapter,  there are two best styles for laying out templates.

- 2 - Tier Template Architecture like:

  templates/
      base.html
      dashboard.html # extends base.html
      profiles/
          profile_details.html
          profile_form.html

which is the style you are using

- 3 - Tier Template Architecture like:

  templates/
      base.html
      dashboard.html # extends base.html
      profiles/
          base_profile.html # extends base.html
          profile_details.html # extends base_profile.html
          profile_form.html # extends base_profile.html

The author said the 2-tier architecture is best for sites with a consistent overall layout from app to app.
And the 3-tier architecture is best for websites where each section requires a distinctive layout.

I highly recommend this book for the best practices in using Djang.
[https://www.amazon.com/Two-Scoops-Django-Best-Practices/dp/0981467342](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981467342)